# Out of memory exception on selection of image from gallery

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am creating an application in which i am creating an album in which i am selecting images from gallery but when i am uploading images of larger size i am receiving outofmemoryexception in spite of compressing  the image.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

       Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
       String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

       Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
         filePathColumn, null, null, null);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       columnindex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
       file_path = cursor.getString(columnindex);
       // Log.e("Attachment Path:", attachmentFile);
      // tv_attach.setText(file_path);
       Log.e("file_path",file_path);
       URI = Uri.parse("file://" + file_path);

       //Retrieve filename and extension

       Filename imageFileName = new Filename(file_path, '/', '.');
       extension=imageFileName.extension();
       fileName=imageFileName.filename();
       System.out.println("Extension = " + imageFileName.extension());
       System.out.println("Filename = " + imageFileName.filename());
       //System.out.println("Path = " + imageFileName.path());
       cursor.close();

       uploadImageName=fileName+"."+extension;
       imagename.setText(uploadImageName);


       /*ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
       imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(  file_path));*/

       Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);
       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //compress to which format you want.
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
   //           image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);


     // String  image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
        albumThumbnail = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);

      }
}
```

Logcat:-

```
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:433)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:276)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942): at com.example.freejeetoproject.Base64.encodeBytes(Base64.java:834)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at com.example.freejeetoproject.Base64.encodeBytes(Base64.java:719)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at com.example.freejeetoproject.CreateAlbum.onActivityResult(CreateAlbum.java:152)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3988)  
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2651)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2697)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:124)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:998)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-03 18:41:08.680: E/AndroidRuntime(1942):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: resize the image size before your set the image in your app and use       `large heap="true"` in manifest file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55046/discussion-between-pratik-and-neha).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_path);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); 
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);

//add this line
image.recycle();
image = null;
```

Bitmaps take a lot of memory, you should release the bitmap so more memory comes available